# How does Objective C decide which C Data Structure are allocated on Heap vs Stack?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

How does Objective C decides allocation on heap vs Stack?
e.g Take a CG framework, there are some classes which has no pointer classes ( or reference classes ) designed which gets allocated on stack. So does that mean only reference object gets created on heap and non reference objects created on stack? What if the data structure is large and takes big memory to allocate? Can Objective C still create such data structure on Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C class instances are always allocated on the heap. C structs and data types like ints and floats are allocated on the stack, unless `malloc()` or its ilk are explicitly used to allocate them on the heap instead.

Comment: OK, here is what I understand after further reading in to the documentation. Objects including its instance variable (primitive or object pointer/reference) gets allocated on heap. When the method is invoked on object, the local variable gets allocated on stacks. So stack comes in to existence only when methods are invoked on object.

Answer (score 0):

It follows the exact same rules as C.